# Jenkins job not using installed maven

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm having an issue with running a test suite through Jenkins and I can't figure out why it's failing.

My job is set up with maven and according to others, maven is set up on the jenkins server (I don't have permission to check myself). The job is set to run on a specific node using labels (can't check the settings on the labels myself either).

This is the error I get when I run (more or less).

```
Running as SYSTEM
Installer "Extract *.zip/*.tar.gz" cannot be used to install "mvn.3.5.2" on the node "SELECTEDNODE"
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on SELECTEDNODE in workspace E:...
Installer "Extract *.zip/*.tar.gz" cannot be used to install "mvn.3.5.2" on the node "SELECTEDNODE"
using credential ABCD
Installer "Extract *.zip/*.tar.gz" cannot be used to install "mvn.3.5.2" on the node "SELECTEDNODE"
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
...
...
Installer "Extract *.zip/*.tar.gz" cannot be used to install "mvn.3.5.2" on the node "SELECTEDNODE"
Installer "Extract *.zip/*.tar.gz" cannot be used to install "mvn.3.5.2" on the node "SELECTEDNODE"
ERROR: Maven Home null doesnt exist
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

This message keeps repeating
`Installer "Extract *.zip/*.tar.gz" cannot be used to install "mvn.3.5.2" on the node "SELECTEDNODE"` even though I have this version of maven installed on the selected node (I do not know if this version is on the Jenkins server, just that a maven version is on the server. I am assuming it is the correct version as I mentioned it needed to be this version and have not heard otherwise). Is this what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are usually 2 ways to get maven installed for you build. One is on the node server itself and define that maven path in the jenkins node configuration and the other way is to have the maven automatically installed from internet which appears to be the case in your case..when you have multiple maven defined you need to specifically select the maven for your job.